# Blank page returned when the server throw 404 error in Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

I'm trying to configure a custom page for 404 error in spring. My application also has spring security configured.

This is the configuration in web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

404.jsp is accessing by browser through the correct url. But when there's a 404 error thrown 404.jsp doesnt get displayed. instead a blank page is shown.

Any pointers on how i can fix this issue ? Thanks in advance.

**Edited**

this is how my web.xml looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/application-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/webflow-context.xml            
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <description>sitemesh filter</description>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <!-- DO NOT define any filter mappings above to the spring security filter-->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>languages</param-name>
        <param-value>en,sv</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>i18nFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.example.filter.InternationalizationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>i18nFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajax</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajax</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajax/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**Updated with the spring configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd       
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.controller" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />     

    <mvc:view-controller path="/index.html" view-name="home"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
             class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
             p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
             p:suffix=".jsp"/>     

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:ApplicationResources</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Try to post your controller

Comment: where is the location of 404.jsp? that is inside of WEB-INF or some where else..?

Comment: @Abdelhak I dont have a controller with the url mapping "/404.jsp" i was assumed that if there spring cannot find a specific url 404 error would be thrown and then the relevant 404.jsp page will be displayed.

Comment: you need to have one

Comment: @Nalla i have placed the 404.jsp inside web pages outside of WEB-INF.

Comment: I guess you have a web.xml post it

Comment: @Abdelhak i was following this url. http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/404-error-code-is-not-working-in-spring-mvc/ .

Comment: @ChathruakaWaas: have you configured view resolver to /WEB-INF/** or webapps?

Comment: @Nalla yes. i've done that part.  <bean id="viewResolver"
             class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
             p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
             p:suffix=".jsp"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try with this config:

Change

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

To

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

and add this in your spring config

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/404.html" view-name="404"/>
```

Comment: Still no luck. Its giving the same blank page.

Comment: I've also configured spring security in this application. Can that have a impact on this issue ?

Comment: Make sur that you have a page 404.jsp in your /WEB-INF/jsp/.
If still not working, it may be that your spring security configuration have a impcat, try to disable the spring security filter in your web.xml and look if it works.